# ColdFusion2016 services are not getting started

Tags: coldfusion, port, iis-8, coldfusion-2016, server-administration

ColdFusion2016 services are not getting started, It was running since last year now they are stopped suddenly, while I'm checking the cf-out logs it says

"Either the server is already running or some other application is using the HTTP port"

CF-Error logs says "failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak."

I have checked no other application is using it except coldFusion.

When I stop IIS site then ColdFusion services gets started.

Can any one help me here.

Comment: While installation, did you change the port for CF to port 80?

Comment: yes, it was running fine, suddenly it has stopped working.

Comment: The thing is that the default port for IIS website is 80 and if you set ColdFusion internal server to run on the same port it will conflict each other.